# Checking file input type in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am a newb to react and was trying to find a function to check for specific file format type(mp4,flv,,ect) when ever i upload something using react besides using dropzone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add the [`accept=""`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-accept) attribute to your `<input type="file">` to allow the user to only select files of a certain type.

For instance,

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*">
```

will accept all video, and

```
<input type="file" accept=".mp4,.flv">
```

will accept files with those extensions.

Answer (score 6):

Note that the `accept` attribute doesn't work as a validation tool, as files should be validated on the server.
The `accept` attribute used for hinting the browser to show files that match the value of `accept`.
Therefore the user will be able to choose any file type he wants.